# Replace tab inside double quotes as space Sed, Regexp

Tags: sed

Hello Sed/Regexp experts, Need some help,

I have a file with below contents, need to replace tabs as space inside double quotes.
Note `\t` is tab.

```
1 \t 2 \t 3 \t "4 \t 5 \t 6" \t 7
```

Expected output:

```
1 \t 2 \t 3 \t "4 5 6" \t 7
```

Matching quotes and tired replacing the tabs to space but it replaces the content inside the quotes.

```
sed '/\s/s/".*"/"  "/' 1.txt
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples Only, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk` using `RT` variable of `awk` to deal with values between `"...."`.

```
awk -v RS='"[^*]*"'  'RT{gsub(/\t/,OFS,RT);ORS=RT;print};END{ORS="";print}' Input_file
```

Comment: Hi Ravinder, RT is not supported option in AIX, do u have any other option to perform the same

Comment: @SakthiLingam, Hi Sakthi, If possible you can install `gawk` in your system. Till then let me check on if I could write an alternative on same, cheers.

Comment: @SakthiLingam, Ok, I am coming up with solution: `awk '{totValue="";while(match($0,/"[^"]*"/)){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);gsub(/\t/,OFS,val);totValue=(totValue?totValue OFS:"") (substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val);$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)};print totValue}'  Input_file` this should work in POSIX `awk` also, kindly do check it and let me know then how it goes. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks this works good , only issue I am seeing is below. The output i got is 1 \t 2 \t 3 \t "4 5 6"  , I have lost the remaining data after double quotes ended. My expected output is like 1 \t 2 \t 3 \t "4 5 6" \t 7

Comment: @SakthiLingam, please try like: `awk '{totValue="";while(match($0,/"[^"]*"/)){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);gsub(/\t/,OFS,val);totValue=(totValue?totValue OFS:"") (substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val);$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)};print totValue $0}'  Input_file` let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for your time, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `sed` solution using label:

```bash
sed -E -e :a -e 's/("[^\t"]*)\t([^"]*")/\1 \2/; ta' file

1    2   3   "4 5 6"   7
```

---

However, it is easier to do this using `awk` by using `"` as field delimiter and change every even numbered field (which will be inside the quote):

```bash
awk '
BEGIN {FS=OFS="\""}
{
   for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2)
      gsub(/\t/, " ", $i)
} 1' file

1    2   3   "4 5 6"     7
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava, Thanks for your prompt response, in case i have content like this { 1 \t 2\t "3 \t "4 \t 5" \t 6" } my expected output will need be like this {1\t 2\t "3 "4 5" 6"} , what changes are required in the above codes

Comment: No change required as both `sed` and `awk` commands work fine as long as quotes are balanced.

Answer (score 0):

with python using indexes and regex - re.sub

```
st = r'1    2   3   "4  5   6"  7'

l_ind = st.index('"')
r_ind = st.rindex('"')

new_st = st[:l_ind] + re.sub(r'\s+', r' ', st[l_ind:r_ind]) + st[r_ind:]

1    2   3   "4 5 6"  7
```

another version using re.sub and re.findall

```
re.sub(r'".*?"',re.sub(r'\s+', r' ', re.findall(r'".*?"', st)[0]), st)

1    2   3   "4 5 6"  7
```

- re.findall(r'".*?"', st)[0] - find the string in double quotes
- re.sub(r'\s+', r' ', - compress the multiple space to one inside the double quoted string
- re.sub(r'".*?"', - substitute the original double quoted string with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/^([^"]*("[^"\t]*"[^"]*)*"[^"\t]*)\t/\1 /;ta' file
```

Replace the first tab within matched double quotes with a space and repeat until failure.

N.B. This solution caters for lines with multiple matching double quotes.